# Macbook Pro 13 Mid 2012 SSD upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, ssd

I have a MacBook Pro 13 Mid 2012 with 4 GB RAM. I want to upgrade it to a SSD drive. I have 2 questions:

1. Is it advisable to do that? Can someone who has done that give me some feedback from their experience?
2. Are there any helpful online resources/tutorials etc that you can recommend to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can upgrade the drive in your MacBook Pro 13 Mid 2012 to an SSD. Here is [a detailed guide from iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2012+Hard+Drive+Replacement/10378) specifically on hard drive replacement.

And [here are more tutorials from Other World Computing](http://eshop.macsales.com/installvideos/macbookpro_13_unibody_mid12/) on how to handle various upgrades such as memory, hard drive, battery replacement, etc…

Comment: Thank you. You answer helped a lot. I have upgraded my MacBook Pro to SSD and it all went smoothly.